# spark dataframe trim column and convert

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Scala / Spark, how to convert empty string, like "      ", to "NULL" ? need to trim it first and then convert to "NULL". Thanks.

```
dataframe.na.replace("cut", Map(" " -> "NULL")).show //wrong
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a simple function to do it. First a couple of imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{trim, length, when}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

and the definition:

```
def emptyToNull(c: Column) = when(length(trim(c)) > 0, c)
```

Finally a quick test:

```
val df = Seq(" ", "foo", "", "bar").toDF
df.withColumn("value", emptyToNull($"value"))
```

which should yield following result:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
| null|
|  foo|
| null|
|  bar|
+-----+
```

If you want to replace empty string with **string** `"NULL` you can add `otherwise` clause:

```
def emptyToNullString(c: Column) = when(length(trim(c)) > 0, c).otherwise("NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the package below to resolve issue

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.trim
```